# How to set the textcolor for a UILabel, which I get using the tag?

Tags: uiview, uicolor, textcolor

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:thisTag].layer setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't get an error message; otherwise you would probably have posted it. So I assume the following:
`thisTag` is a tag that does not exist in your view hierarchy. In this case, `viewWithTag:` will return `nil`. Then you send the message `layer`, and then `setTextColor:` to `nil`, which does nothing.
If `viewWithTag:` would return a `UIView` object, you would get its `layer` property, and then send it `setTextColor:`, which is not defined for a `CALayer` object, and thus would give you an error message.

Comment: yes, thank you. I got a UIView object, for which I could'nt set the textcolot property.

Comment: I added [(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:thisTag] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]]; and now its perfect.

Comment: Great! I did not think about this obvious possibility. Thanks for letting me know.